# Laravel Dose not redirect to base url

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

**My first URL is**
`http://mydomain.localhost/myfolder/public/test`

**When I use this command on my controller to redirect**

```
return redirect()->route('test.index', $domain);
```

redirect me to `http://mydomain.localhost/test` and I want to redirect me to `http://mydomain.localhost/myfolder/public/test`

Note: I know about `redirect()->back()` but I don't want to use it. Because sometimes I want the redirect to other pages.

**My route:**

```
Route::group(array('domain' => '{account}.localhost'), function () {
   Route::resource('/test', 'testController', 
      ['middleware' => 'Subdomain', function ($account) {
}]);
```

Comment: You are redirecting to a named route and haven't provided that route config.

Comment: Looks like your web server is not configured correctly.

Comment: write down you routes and explain more

Comment: I edit my post and write my route

Answer (score 1):

Firstly check your route list and find out your expected route. Then

```
return redirect()->route('test.index');
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure APP_URL on .env file. because default APP_URL is your localhost.

Comment: Can you please add this to your .htaccess file.

RewriteBase /myfolder/public